What is the maximum size of a Solana block?
What is the maximum size of a Solana block? According to an old reddit thread it's 76.8MB, according to various publications it's 128MB (these don't cite any real source though, I'm guessing they're just quoting each other), so answers seem to vary. I tried looking through the Solana docs, but couldn't find a clear answer either.

The way I understood it, it is dynamic. The size to measure it is in compute units (CU). One block has 48 million CUs and whatever you can fit in this, is the block.
So approximately 50 MB?

Do you have a source on this? According to https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/14702/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-cus-a-solana-transaction-must-process it is possible to build a tx that processes just one CU and passing accounts doesn't cost CUs, so in theory I could pass 48M txs at 1 CU and 1232 bytes in size,  resulting in a block more than 50 GB large. I have a hard time believing we wouldn't hit some other limit when doing this
